# C# WPF Pulsing Button

Tags: c#, wpf

I need some help figuring out how to make a button pulse its background colour.  I use the style below to create the buttons and would like the buttons background colour to pulse (different shades of colour) when in normal state.  The purpose is to draw the users attention to the button.

Ideally I would like this to occur after a certain period of inactivity.  Is it possible to do this within the style or do I need to create a complete custom UserControl ?  If it is possible I would appreciate it if someone could provide sample code illustrating how to achieve this.

I believe it should be possible to do the following:
1.  Create a ControlTemplate.Resources section and add a Storyboard which defines the animation to be used.
  1.1 What would the storyboard look like and how does it relate to the actual button background colours
  1.2 How would one add a delay to the start of the storyboard (so it only gets triggered after a period of inactivity (i.e. no click on the button)
2. Add a trigger somehow to start the storyboard. how to do that for the normal state of the button.

```
<Style x:Key="ContinueButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid x:Name="grid">
                    <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ThemeSolidColorBrushGreen}" BorderThickness="2" Background="{StaticResource ThemeSolidColorBrushGreen}">

                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextElement.Foreground="White" 
                                          TextElement.FontSize="{Binding Source={StaticResource settingsProvider}, Path=Default.FontSizeParagraph}" TextElement.FontFamily="{Binding Source={StaticResource settingsProvider}, Path=Default.FontFamily}" TextElement.FontWeight="Bold"></ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource ThemeSolidColorBrushGreen}">

                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="grid" Value="0.25"/>
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Animation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EventTrigger to achieve this. Just replace the ControlTemplate.Trigger section of your code with the following code

```
                          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation  Storyboard.TargetName="border" AutoReverse="True"  
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                                             To="Blue" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="GreenYellow"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <!--<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="Gray"/>
                                </Trigger>-->
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="grid" Value="0.25"/>
                                </Trigger>

                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```